How to speed up NIntegrate inside a module with input as interpolating functions?
I have the following Mathematica code for Numerical Integration:
\[Alpha] = 1; l = 1; r0 = 1;

\[Mu] = (-l^2 q^2 + r0^6)/r0^2;

f[r_, q_] = 1 - \[Mu]/r^4 - (q^2 l^2)/r^6;

g[r_, q_] = r^4/l^4 f[r, q];

h[r_, q_] = f[r, q] r^4/l^4 (D[f[r, q], r]/f[r, q] - 4/r);

V[r_, x_, k_, q_] = k^2/f[r, q] + (4 r^4)/l^4 \[Alpha]^2 x^2;

delyb[r_, q_] = (D[g[r, q], r] - 2 h[r, q])/(4 Sqrt[g[r, q]]) // 
   Simplify;

Veff[r_, x_, k_, q_] = 
  V[r, x, k, 
     q] + (Sqrt[g[r, q]] D[delyb[r, q], r] - (delyb[r, q])^2) // 
   Simplify;

s1[r_, q_] := NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[g[\[Chi], q]], {\[Chi], 1.001, r}]

rsol[s_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] := 
 r1 /. FindRoot[s1[r1, q] == s, {r1, 1}, Evaluated -> False, 
   Method -> "Newton", PrecisionGoal -> 6, AccuracyGoal -> 6]

precomputedR = 
  Table[{s, q, 
    r1 /. FindRoot[s1[r1, q] == s, {r1, 1}, Evaluated -> False, 
      Method -> "Newton", PrecisionGoal -> 6, AccuracyGoal -> 6]}, {s,
     0, 1.2, 0.001}, {q, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1}];

rInterp = Interpolation[Flatten[precomputedR, 1], Method -> "Spline"]

eq[s2_, k_, q_] := (-\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]\((\[Psi][s, x])\)\) - \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(s, s\)]\((\[Psi][s, x])\)\) + 
   Veff[rInterp[s2, q], x, k, q] \[Psi][s, x])

eig[k_, q_] := 
 NDEigensystem[{eq[s, k, q], 
   DirichletCondition[\[Psi][s, x] == 0, True]}, \[Psi][s, x], {s, 
   0.01, 0.8}, {x, -10, 10}, 100, 
  Method -> {"Arnoldi", MaxIterations -> 10^5}]

{EigValues, EigFunctions} = eig[5, 0.2];

matrixElementY[n_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ] := Module[{psiN, psiM},
  psiN = EigFunctions[[n]];
  psiM = EigFunctions[[m]];
  NIntegrate[Conjugate[psiN]*s*psiM, {s, 0.01, 0.8}, {x, -10, 10}, 
   Method -> "LocalAdaptive", AccuracyGoal -> 10]]

yMatrix = Chop[Table[matrixElementY[n, m], {n, 1, 28}, {m, 1, 28}]]

Here, the output of yMatrix is taking forever to compute. Any help in this regard would be highly beneficial!

It might be worth noting that your 1/Sqrt[g[\[Chi], q]] is analytically integrable. Looking at the FullForm of this integrand suggests that you should rewrite it using 1/Sqrt[g[\[Chi], q]] /. {Power[u_, Rational[-1, 2]] :> \[Chi] Power[\[Chi]^2 u // Expand, Rational[-1, 2]]}. Then its indefinite integral is given by Integrate[..., \[Chi]], which evaluates to give an expression involving EllipticF.

For me LocalAdaptive is usually slower than GlobalAdaptive, except when it's not. Also look up "InterpolationPointsSubdivision". Maybe that would help.

Since the EigFunctions are real-valued, you only need to calculate the matrix elements for the upper triangle (it will be symmetric about the diagonal).

I'm just going to highlight the things I've changed in your code, and then I'll put it all together at the bottom.
Note I am not changing anything about your interpretation of this problem, as I don't know any background information about it. If @user57481's comment about the x integration bounds needing to be 0 to 10 is correct, it would invalidate this answer, as my simplifications mostly rely on the symmetry of the eigenfunctions around x =0.
I first start by using @Stephen Luttrell's comment to get an analytical expression for s1:
new = 1/Sqrt[
     g[χ, q]] /. {Power[u_, 
      Rational[-1, 2]] :> χ Power[χ^2 u // Expand, 
       Rational[-1, 2]]};
indef[χ_, q_] := Integrate[new, χ] // Evaluate
s1[r_, q_] := (indef[r, q] - indef[1001/1000, q]) // Evaluate


precomputedR takes about 10s to run now.

Notice that the imaginary values in precomputedR are all very small:
Im@Flatten@precomputedR // MinMax
(*{-4.97811*10^-13, 4.41481*10^-13}*)

So we can just Chop them before interpolation:
rInterp = 
 Interpolation[Chop@Flatten[precomputedR, 1], Method -> "Spline"]



After calculating your eigenfunctions, you may observe that they are all either even or odd symmetry in x. Since we are integrating from -10 to 10 in x, all of the odd symmetry eigenfunction pairs (odd * even or even * odd) will integrate to 0, while the even (same symmetry for both eigenfunctions) pairs will just be twice the integral from x = 0 to 10.
Also, note that all of the eigenfunctions are real-valued, so Conjugate has no effect. With these two observations in mind I slightly tweak your definition of matrixElementY:
matrixElementY[n_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{psiN, psiM, integrand},
      psiN = EigFunctions[[n]];
      psiM = EigFunctions[[m]];

     2* NIntegrate[psiN*s*psiM, {s, 0.01, 0.8}, {x, 0, 10}, 
        Method -> "LocalAdaptive", AccuracyGoal -> 10]
    ]

And define some fast symmetry testers for the eigenfunctions around x = 0 by using coarse summation steps in x and s
oddSymmetryTester[f_, s_, x_] := f[s, x] + f[s, -x] // Chop
evenSymmetryTester[f_, s_, x_] := f[s, x] - f[s, -x] // Chop

oddSymmetryQ[f_] := 
 Sum[oddSymmetryTester[f, s, x], {x, 0, 10}, {s, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1}] == 0
evenSymmetryQ[f_] := 
 Sum[evenSymmetryTester[f, s, x], {x, 0, 10}, {s, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1}] == 0

determineSymmetry[f_] :=
 If[oddSymmetryQ[f], -1, If[evenSymmetryQ[f], 1, "Neither"]]

And calculate the symmetry of each eigenfunction around x = 0 (note they are all either even or odd, none of them are Neither):
ef = (Head /@ EigFunctions[[1 ;; 28]]);
symmetryList = determineSymmetry /@ ef

(*{1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, \
-1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1}*)


We want all the eigenfunction pairs that have matching symmetry (so the integrand is non-zero). We also know that matrixElementY[n,m] == matrixElementY[m,n] since the eigenfunctions are real-valued, so we can greatly reduce the number of eigenfunction pairs for which we need to compute integrals:
indices = Flatten[Outer[List, Range[28], Range[28]], 1];

(*eigenFunctions are real-valued so matrix is symmetric. Only need to \
compute upper triangle and mirror afterwards*)
indices = Select[indices, #[[1]] <= #[[2]] &];

(*select pairs with the same symmetry*)
nonZeroIndices = 
  Select[indices, 
   symmetryList[[First@#]] == symmetryList[[Last@#]] &];



And now create the upper triangle of our symmetric matrix using ParallelMap, and mirroring it by reversing the nonZeroIndices and using SparseArray. This takes about 35 s on my laptop with 4 parallel kernels running:
AbsoluteTiming[
 upperTriangle = 
  ParallelMap[matrixElementY @@ # &, nonZeroIndices];
 sparArgs = 
  Join[Thread[nonZeroIndices -> upperTriangle], 
   Thread[Reverse /@ nonZeroIndices -> upperTriangle]];
 matrix = SparseArray[sparArgs, {28, 28}] // Normal;
 ]
(*{35.0802, Null}*)

And MatrixPlot:
MatrixPlot[matrix, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]



Putting this all together:
\[Alpha] = 1; l = 1; r0 = 1;

\[Mu] = (-l^2 q^2 + r0^6)/r0^2;

f[r_, q_] = 1 - \[Mu]/r^4 - (q^2 l^2)/r^6;

g[r_, q_] = r^4/l^4 f[r, q];

h[r_, q_] = f[r, q] r^4/l^4 (D[f[r, q], r]/f[r, q] - 4/r);

V[r_, x_, k_, q_] = k^2/f[r, q] + (4 r^4)/l^4 \[Alpha]^2 x^2;

delyb[r_, q_] = (D[g[r, q], r] - 2 h[r, q])/(4 Sqrt[g[r, q]]) // 
         Simplify;

Veff[r_, x_, k_, q_] = 
      V[r, x, k, 
     
          
     q] + (Sqrt[g[r, q]] D[delyb[r, q], r] - (delyb[r, q])^2) // 
         Simplify;


new = 1/Sqrt[
          g[\[Chi], q]] /. {Power[u_, 
            Rational[-1, 2]] :> \[Chi] Power[\[Chi]^2 u // Expand, 
              Rational[-1, 2]]};
indef[\[Chi]_, q_] := Integrate[new, \[Chi]] // Evaluate
s1[r_, q_] := (indef[r, q] - indef[1001/1000, q]) // Evaluate

precomputedR = 
      Table[{s, q, 
            r1 /. 
          
     FindRoot[s1[r1, q] == s, {r1, 1001/1000}, Evaluated -> False, 
                  Method -> "Newton", PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
            AccuracyGoal -> 6]}, {s,
             0, 1.2, 0.001}, {q, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1}];

rInterp = 
 Interpolation[Chop@Flatten[precomputedR, 1], Method -> "Spline"]

eq[s2_, k_, q_] := (-\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]\((\[Psi][s, x])\)\) - \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(s, s\)]\((\[Psi][s, x])\)\) + 
      Veff[rInterp[s2, q], x, k, q] \[Psi][s, x])

eig[k_, q_] := 
  NDEigensystem[{eq[s, k, q], 
      DirichletCondition[\[Psi][s, x] == 0, True]}, \[Psi][s, 
   x], {s, 
      0.01, 0.8}, {x, -10, 10}, 100, 
    Method -> {"Arnoldi", MaxIterations -> 10^5}]

{EigValues, EigFunctions} = eig[5, 0.2];

matrixElementY[n_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{psiN, psiM, integrand},
      psiN = EigFunctions[[n]];
      psiM = EigFunctions[[m]];
  
     2* NIntegrate[psiN*s*psiM, {s, 0.01, 0.8}, {x, 0, 10}, 
        Method -> "LocalAdaptive", AccuracyGoal -> 10]
    ]

oddSymmetryTester[f_, s_, x_] := f[s, x] + f[s, -x] // Chop
evenSymmetryTester[f_, s_, x_] := f[s, x] - f[s, -x] // Chop

oddSymmetryQ[f_] := 
  Sum[oddSymmetryTester[f, s, x], {x, 0, 10}, {s, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1}] == 
  0
evenSymmetryQ[f_] := 
  Sum[evenSymmetryTester[f, s, x], {x, 0, 10}, {s, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1}] == 0

determineSymmetry[f_] :=
  If[oddSymmetryQ[f], -1, If[evenSymmetryQ[f], 1, "Neither"]]

ef = (Head /@ EigFunctions[[1 ;; 28]]);
symmetryList = determineSymmetry /@ ef;

indices = Flatten[Outer[List, Range[28], Range[28]], 1];

(*eigenFunctions are real value so matrix is symmetric. Only need to \
computer upper triangle and mirror afterwards*)
indices = Select[indices, #[[1]] <= #[[2]] &];

(*select pairs with the same symmetry*)
nonZeroIndices = 
    Select[indices, 
      symmetryList[[First@#]] == symmetryList[[Last@#]] &];


AbsoluteTiming[
  upperTriangle = 
    ParallelMap[matrixElementY @@ # &, nonZeroIndices];
  sparArgs = 
    Join[Thread[nonZeroIndices -> upperTriangle], 
      Thread[Reverse /@ nonZeroIndices -> upperTriangle]];
  matrix = SparseArray[sparArgs, {28, 28}] // Normal;
  ]


Such a well thought and logical answer. Kudos!

Actually, my final aim is to calculate the OTOC which is why I needed the matrix elements along with eigenvalues.

As Stephen Luttrell noted, the value of s1[r1,q] is an analytically integrable elliptic function of the following result for your particular case, the result being:
-(((0. + 
   0.0000632298 I)  (1. Sqrt[
    1 - (999.5 (2 + q^2))/(-3 + Sqrt[1 - 4 q^2])] Sqrt[
    1 + (999.5 (2 + q^2))/(3 + Sqrt[1 - 4 q^2])]
     r Sqrt[-1 + q^2 (1 - 1/r^2) + r^4]
     EllipticF[
     I ArcSinh[31.6149 Sqrt[(2 + q^2)/(3 + Sqrt[1 - 4 q^2])]], (
     3 + Sqrt[1 - 4 q^2])/(3 - Sqrt[1 - 4 q^2])] - 
   11183.1  Sqrt[0.004006 + 0.001997 q^2]  (-1 + r^2)^(3/2)  Sqrt[
    1 - (2 (2 + q^2))/((-3 + Sqrt[1 - 4 q^2]) (-1 + r^2))]  Sqrt[
    1 + (2 (2 + q^2))/((3 + Sqrt[1 - 4 q^2]) (-1 + r^2))]
      EllipticF[
     I ArcSinh[(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(2 + q^2)/(3 + Sqrt[1 - 4 q^2])])/
       Sqrt[-1 + r^2]], (3 + Sqrt[1 - 4 q^2])/(
     3 - Sqrt[1 - 4 q^2])]))/(Sqrt[0.004006 + 0.001997 q^2]
   Sqrt[(2 + q^2)/(3 + Sqrt[1 - 4 q^2])]
   r  Sqrt[-1 + q^2 (1 - 1/r^2) + r^4])).
    

Second, the s "variable" should not be allowed to be zero in the bounds of precomputedR functional relationship as that will give 1/Sqrt[0] errors.
Third, q in precomputedR should not be less than 1.001 as defined in the s1 integral relationship (otherwise it will be undefined and not necessarily a real solution).  In other words, s1[1.001,q] is undefined.  Please make sure that all relationships call s as above 1.001. Note that q can hold a value of 1.001.
Next, rinterp is called in eq[s2_,k_,q_] as a function of s2 and q but it is not defined as such.  This may give additional errors.
Then I would load the r1 solutions outside of the table to separate out a few syntax errors:
  r1[s_, q_]:=Re[FindRoot[s1[r1, q] == s, {r1, 1.1}, Method -> "Newton", 
PrecisionGoal -> 5, AccuracyGoal -> 6]];

Whn observing the values that the s1 function takes in a contour plot against r1 and q, it appears to have a range of ca. 7 to ca. 28 over the specified domain.  That is what you should then call in the prcomputerR function definition for FindRoot.
In order to better assist, what are you calculating the rsol function for?  Since it isn't utilized in subsequent calculations, I'm assuming that it is an important solution for comparison with the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions.
I must admit the last three function calls are a bit puzzling to me.  eig[5, 0.2] should NOT be all of the EigValues and EigFunctions, unless you are forcing a particular wavefunction and looking to plot the solutions, as defined in eig[k,q].  Furthermore, the x value in NIntegrate should be above zero for matrixElementY definition.  Lastly, r1 should be a functions of s1 and, in turn r1 and q and only looking at the real roots of the equations.

Thank you for the answer. rsol was just a precursor to precomputedR, meaning I just wished to check if FindRoot is giving right values or not. I forgot to remove it while posting my question to Stack; my apologies!
